# Biweekly Email alert to user if opportunity stage is not moving forward

Tags: workflow, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

How to send by weekly email reminder alerts to a user on account object if its related opportunities of certain type is not moving to "Closed Loss/Won" stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow, Process Builder or even Trigger work only if there is a change in data(Change of records field)

If the opportunities are kept as it is for few days, nothing will fire.

You have to go via different approach of Scheduler/Batch and workflows.

1. Create a field on Account, Last_Opportunity_Close_Date__c(Date)
2. Create a WF rule on Opportunity, When its Closed update its Parent Account's Last_Opportunity_Close_Date__c field to that of todays date.
3. Create A scheduler cum Batch. Which will query all Accounts where  Last_Opportunity_Close_Date__c is null or Last_Opportunity_Close_Date__c is Older than last X days, iterate and send an email to its owner.
4. Schedule your scheduler to run 2 days a Week using Schedule Apex UI in Apex-Classes section.